# Prove that if G is a graph with $\chi$(G-v-w)=$\chi$(G)-2 for every pair of vertices v and w in G, then G is complete.

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that if G is a graph with  $\chi$(G-v-w)=$\chi$(G)-2 for every pair of vertices v and w in G, then G is complete.

I think I can use contradiction method but I don't know how to do.

Comment: Thank you for the link but why there are two vertices with same color if G is not complete? Is there any theorem I can use for it?

Comment: There are two vertices *not connected to each other* if $G$ is not complete, so you can give them the same color if you've found a way to color the remainder of the graph.